# better way to determine quarter boundaries dates

Tags: java, date, kotlin

I have this code that works :

```
    private fun getCycleBoundaries(cycleNumber: Int, year: Int): Array<Date> {

        return when (cycleNumber) {
            1 -> arrayOf(DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-01-01T00:00:00"), DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-03-31T23:59:59"))
            2 -> arrayOf(DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-04-01T00:00:00"), DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-06-30T23:59:59"))
            3 -> arrayOf(DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-07-01T00:00:00"), DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-09-30T23:59:59"))
            4 -> arrayOf(DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-10-01T00:00:00"), DATE_FORMATER.parse("$year-12-31T23:59:59"))
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("$cycleNumber is nor a valid cycle number")
        }
    }
```

This code takes a cycle number : 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 and a year
And it returns an arrays of 2 dates (the start and the end of the quarter)

For example if i call :

```
 getCycleBoundaries(1, 2019)
```

I expect :

```
2019-01-01T00:00:00 and 2019-03-31T23:59:59
```

As said it works but i'm not happy with the code and was trying to do it better.
Is there a better way to achieve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Since the code works and you look for general adivce, consider posting this on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). One thing I see: If `Date` is `java.util.Date`, consider using the more modern [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) if possible. If you can add libraries, you may also find use in [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) of ThreeTen-Extra.

Comment: Thanks finally i used this library

Comment: Or you can use the class [CalendarQuarter](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/CalendarQuarter.html) in my library [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J). It has definitely more power and internationalization than Threeten-Extra.

Answer (score 3):

The `IsoFields` class of java.time may be a bit overlooked. It’s our friend when it comes to manipulating quarters. Sorry that I can write only Java code.

```
public static LocalDate[] getCycleBoundaries(int cycleNumber, int year) {
    YearMonth firstMonthOfQuarter = YearMonth.of(year, 1)
            .with(IsoFields.QUARTER_OF_YEAR, cycleNumber);
    return new LocalDate[] { firstMonthOfQuarter.atDay(1),
            firstMonthOfQuarter.plusMonths(2).atEndOfMonth() };
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(getCycleBoundaries(4, 2019)));
```

Output in this case:

> [2019-10-01, 2019-12-31]

Tip: use half-open intervals. While users usually prefer to have a period in the calendar given as first and last day, in a computer program it’s generally more convenient to represent a period as a *from* date *inclusive* and a *to* date *exclusive*. So a quarter as the first day of the quarter and the first day of the following quarter. And if you know already that the period is a quarter, then just the first day of the quarter and nothing more. The rest can be easily calculated as needed.

Answer (score 2):

## `Quarter` & `YearQuarter`

Add the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. You can access handy classes that extend the features of the modern *java.time* classes built into Java and defined in JSR 310.

The [`Quarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/Quarter.html) enum class represents generic quarters without a year. Use this class across your code rather than a mere integer 1-4. Sound so makes your code more self-documenting, provides type-safety, and ensures valid values.

```
Quarter q = Quarter.Q2 ;
```

The [`YearQuarter`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html) represents a quarter in a specific year.

```
YearQuarter yq = YearQuarter.of( 2019 , q ) ;
```

Get the date of the first day of that quarter.

```
LocalDate start = yq.atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Get the date of last day of quarter.

```
LocalDate lastDate = yq.atEndOfQuarter() ;
```

Or for half-open date ranges, get the first day of the next quarter.

```
LocalDate stop = yq.plusQuarters( 1L ).atDay( 1 ) ;
```

Rather than return a mere array of the dates, use the `LocalDateRange` class also included in *ThreeTen-Extra*. This class offers powerful comparison methods like contains, abuts, overlaps, and more.

```
LocalDateRange qDates = LocalDateRange.of( start , stop ) ;
```